# Promise.race is not a function in my Bluebird installation

Tags: javascript, promise, electron, bluebird

I am trying to figure out an error I am receiving with Promise.race. 
This is my code:

```
   function startPromiseRace(data) {
     return Promise.race([executeFirstPromise(data), timeout()]);
   }
```

Then the promises:

```
function executeFirstPromise(data) {
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {      
 resolve("Promise completed");   
});
}

function timeout() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let id = setTimeout(() => {
     clearTimeout(id);
    reject(new Error("Timeout limit reached"))
  }, 900);
});
}
```

My problem is that when I call StartPromiseRace, it launches the promises but the it gives me the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Promise.race is not a function
```

I am using Electron 2.0.9 and Bluebird 3.5.2

Any sugestions?

P.S In VSCode I can see the definition of Promise.race but at runtime it says Promise.race is undefined

Update 1: At runtime in the console I can use Promise.all but Promise.race or Promise.any results in the same error as above.

Update 2: I am using npm to install the node module Bluebird and inside bluebird.core.js the following is noted:

> - bluebird build version 3.5.2
> - Features enabled: core
> - Features disabled: race, call_get, generators, map, nodeify, promisify, 
>     props, reduce, settle, some, using, timers, filter, any, each

Is there another way of using Promis.race or Promis.any in Bluebird 3.5.2?

Comment: What is `Promise`, did you import Bluebird into that variable or do you want to use native promises?

Comment: hey, I was debugging my code and Promise is instantiated as:`Promise bluebird.core.js:2207 ƒ Promise(executor)`

Comment: Hm, that's really weird, as [Bluebird *does* have `Promise.race`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.race.html)

Comment: This sounds like perhaps a bundling problem where the import of Bluebird is not working correctly.  I'd suggest some debugging code to test if Bluebird is properly installed when running inside of Electron.

Comment: FYI, there's no need to call `clearTimeout(id)` on a timer that has just fired.  That timer clears itself since `setTimeout()` only ever fires once.

Comment: I looked through the code of bluebird.core.js but couldn't find any referance to Promise.race. I have also tried removing bluebird from node_modules and reinstalling it but it's exactly the same. I am using npm to install it.

Comment: @jfriend00 fair point on setTimeout, I missed that, thanks

Comment: @Bergi found this comments iside bluebird.core: `* bluebird build version 3.5.2
 * Features enabled: core
 * Features disabled: race, call_get, generators, map, nodeify, promisify, props, reduce, settle, some, using, timers, filter, any, each` so apparently they disabled it...

Comment: @jfriend00 fair point, although if you let the following script run for long time, you'll see once the int32 limit is reached, the timer starts counting from its negative and then will eventually reach the id. This means that while it's useless to clearTimer when the timeout happens, two timers might theoretically have the same ID in a long run. `(function run(i) { if (!(i % 100)) console.clear(); console.log(setTimeout(run, 0, i + 1)); }(0));`

Comment: @Mipod Sounds like *you* are running a [custom build](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/tree/2.x#custom-builds) of Bluebird for some reason.

Comment: @Bergi I installed it using `npm install bluebird --save` command so I don't know how that would be possible.

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi - How does calling `clearTimeout()` after the timer fired change your comment at all about two timers eventually having the same id?  I don't get what your comment means.

Comment: @jfriend00 I probably didn't explain myself much, I was actually underlying that it might backfire to clear a timer within a setTimeout because like you said it already fired **and** IDs are not necessarily unique. I was trying to re-enforce your point with an edge case, but I guess it came out really bad. Apology for the confusion, it was rather an extra head up for the OP about cleaning timeouts within callbacks. TL;DR don't ever do that

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi - I was indeed confused about your comment.  OK, but it would be potentially buggy if the timer sub-system allowed reuse of a timerID before the timerID's callback has been called.  One would hope the timer sub-system doesn't do that.  Anyway, yes - further potential reasons not to call `clearTimeout()` on a timer that just fired via `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 "One would hope the timer sub-system doesn't do that" ... I hope daily anything web related works as expected but ... you know, I quite often get disappointed  Anyway, sorry for the OT

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi - Well, given that timers can be set for really long times from now and thus be around for a really long time and interval timers can last forever, I'd be very surprised if the designers didn't protect against reuse of a timer id.  If it was more of a central issue here, either one of us could go examine the source code to see.